# Solaris Studio compiler flags to read old GNU Fortran unformatted file

Tags: fortran

I am using Solaris Studio (developed by Oracle) and having a problem.
I have a unformatted file writed by old version GNU (with 8 bytes padding at begin of a record). If using gfortran to read it, i will use the flag `frecord-marker=8` and read it directly.
Then I want to use Solaris Studio IDE to debug but cannot find any compiling flag that as same as `frecord-marker=8`.

Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: Have you tried the manual? Is your file sequential or direct? (I assume sequential but you should show the code.) There may be no such an option available. Unformatted sequential files are not portable!